# How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix with current year

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
create table student(
  `regdno` varchar(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `course` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contacthome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `contactpersonal` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `coursefee` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (regdno)
)
```

I want to increment my id field like 
`'25/yerar/200','25/yerar/201','25/yerar/202'... etc`. What should I have to do for that? Please let me know any possible way.

Comment: Write a script for it. But actually you don't need it if you choose the proper designn f or your data.

Comment: why? Advocate with proper reasoning please

Comment: You dont need an incremental key which is a string. Use another field  to store the date/year

Answer (score 0):

Dont even try that, instead something like this is a much better idea

```
create table student(
  `regdno` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `regdno_fluf` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   //<- new col for stuff
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `course` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contacthome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `contactpersonal` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `coursefee` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (regdno)
)
```

Now you let MYSQL deal with autoincrementing the `regdno` like normal and you use the `regdno_fluf` column to store whatever extra fluf you want to use.

All you then do is when you come to present anything that needs the extra fluf, you concatenate it to the `regdno` either in the query you run or in the language you are using for your Application

```
SELECT CONCAT(`regdno_fluf`,'/',`regdno`) as fluffed_regdno, .....
```

But any foreign key links you may want to create will still use the nice and simple `regdno`